# Is it TIBCO really a widely used framework?

Tags: frameworks, tibco

I keep finding -quite interesting- job positions that require knowledge of this specific framework. My question is: It's worth gaining laboral experience at TIBCO? Besides the job search related sites, where can I find trustful information regarding the current use of a framework/technology?

And, on which factors does usually depend the success of certain programming framework amongst others?

I want to figure out if TIBCO will have a long-term future. Thank you for any help you can provide on this subject.

(Feel free to edit if the question(s) can be formulated better ^^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIBCO BusinessWorks (I assume you are talking about that specific product, out of the very large TIBCO product selection) is an integration software. As such, you should learn it if you are interested in working in the integration field.
FYI : Integration requires a lot of soft skills and complex problem resolution techniques. It is mostly related to data routing and transport (think: REST-enabling Mainframe software).

As for selecting TIBCO products, I personally believe the company to be a great integration software provider.

TIBCO is a lot more than BW ! Many products deserve attention, such as EMS, Service Grid, BPM, MFT, Spotfire, etc.

How popular really is TIBCO ?

It might be simplistic, but I like to use Google Trends for that sort of questions...

- [TIBCO vs Websphere vs webMethods vs Spring int](http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=TIBCO,%20Datapower,%20Websphere,%20spring%20integration,%20webMethods&cmpt=q) : TIBCO 2nd, Websphere 1st (dropping rapidly)
- [TIBCO alone](http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=TIBCO&cmpt=q) (a steady slow drop, but still strong)
- [TIBCO EMS vs MQ vs Active MQ vs RabbitMQ](http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=TIBCO%20EMS,%20/m/0401cy,%20active%20mq,%20rabbitmq&cmpt=q) : EMS steady (but not high), RabbitMQ rising
- Some topics like [TIBCO Spotfire](http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=tibco%20spotfire) have some more traction...

Comment: Pretty good answer, now I can investigate a little bit more. Thank you :)